# Add StackPanel to WPF DataGrid at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn

I have a Datagrid that is being built dynamically from incoming data using the following:

```
TableData = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"Datainfo.json"));
var listCols = new List<DataColumn>();
var rawData = new DataTable();
foreach (dynamic item in TableData.data)
{
    string columnName = item.Column;
    var column = new DataColumn(columnName);
    string DataType = item.DataType;
    if (DataType == "Int" )
    {
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    }
    else
    {
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    }
    column.Unique = false;
    column.AllowDBNull = true;
    column.AutoIncrement = false;
    listCols.Add(column);
    rawData.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Then I am pushing it to the DataGrid like this:

```
    DataTable ETL = null;
    ETL = rawData;
    ETL.DefaultView.AllowEdit = true;
    DataGridView.DataContext = ETL;
```

I would like to add a StackPanel to each column that includes a TextBox for the Column Name, and a dropdown that has various datatypes in it. It would then have a Apply / Cancel option.

I have been trying to follow similar solutions for adding Expanders to Grids, but I can't figure out how to apply it to a DataGrid since it doesn't have a `.Children()` to `.Add()` to.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/877973/How-Do-I-Add-A-Stackpanel-To-An-Expander-Header-Vi

Is there a way to do what I am asking? I also tried to hide the header row and control the first two rows, but then when I tried loading up the header into a Int column, I get an error, so obviously that isn't a good idea.

Comment: Define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding this to the column header than you must add it as a HeaderTemplate.
Lets say this is the XAML...

```
<Window x:Class="testtestz.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testtestz"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="myGrid">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Id"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then you would do this in the code behind...

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace testtestz
{ 

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnContentRendered(e);

            var cBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));

            myGrid.Columns[0].HeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = cBox };
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a showcase of how to do it. Of course you would have to play with some layout, sizes and simillar stuff to get it to a reasonable point but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this got me closer, but then I started taking a different direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53288632/at-runtime-add-x-number-of-comboboxs-with-selecteditem-to-datagrid-wpf