# At Runtime Add X number of ComboBoxes with SelectedItem to DataGrid (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to create an entire row of `ComboBoxes` in a `DataGrid`. I have made some progress with the following:

```
// Declare it
private DataGridComboBoxColumn CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(string ColumnName) 
{
    string[] data = { "Date", "LEInt", "String" };
    DataGridComboBoxColumn dgCmbCol = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    dgCmbCol.Header = ColumnName;
    dgCmbCol.ItemsSource = data;
    return dgCmbCol;
}

// Later somewhere you can add this to create 20 columns:
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  DataGridComboBoxColumn newColumn = CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce("Column-" +i);
}
// Sadly nothing is shown unless you manually specify a new row and an
// extra column as done here below, but then you get an extra column.
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("|", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add("");
DataGridCombo.DataContext = table;
```

The XAML is kept to a minimum:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

Is there a way to set the default `SelectedValue` of each `ComboBox`? Within my `for` loop I do have access to the desired setting. Also, is there a way to git it to show without adding the extra column? This DataGrid is being lined up with another `DataGrid` that won't have that extra column.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set the default `SelectedValue` of each `ComboBox`?

Add a `DataColumn` to the `DataTable` per `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, and then set the value of the column for each row to the desired selected value:

```
const int n = 20;
DataTable table = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    string columnName = "Column-" + i;
    DataGridCombo.Columns.Add(CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(columnName));
    table.Columns.Add(columnName, typeof(string));
}
table.Rows.Add(new object[n]);
//select some values...
table.Rows[0][1] = "LEInt";
table.Rows[0][5] = "String";
DataGridCombo.DataContext = table;
```

> Also, is there a way to git it to show without adding the extra column?

Set the `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Left` to prevent the `DataGrid` from stretching horizontally:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much mm8, when I tried doing that for some reason I have 20 blank columns, then 2 over (in position 22) for index `[0][1]` I get `LEInt` as a string with no drop down ability, and then a few more over I get `String` for `[0][5]`. When I set a breakpoint and examine `table` it only has the 20 items and things are set in the right place. I think the problem is that in the for loop is `DataGridCombo.Columns.Add(CreateCustomComboBoxDataSouce(columnName));` which adds all those to the `DataGrid` and then `table` is appended to the end. Can we to add the `ComboBox` to `DataTable`?

Comment: I just noticed something. I normally had headers turned off, but that DataGrid has Columns named `Column-0 -Column-19` and then appended to the end is `Column-0 -Column-19` again, and in the second set is where the `LEInt` and `String` are set. Normally I thought Column names had to be unique, but I guess because the DataType is different, it is allowed to repeat?

Comment: It works just fine for me so you are apparently doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much mm8 for your time and effort. I created a sample empty project and pasted in the code and got the same issues. Here is a video showing what happens to me: https://streamable.com/0kghj

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of working around the issue, I eventually came to the conclusion that what I was trying to do was either not possible, or unreasonable. I changed to using a `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation. Here are the relevant snippets:

```
//XAML Layout
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="ComboBoxPanel"  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,0,0,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

//Function to create new box and set options
private ComboBox CreateComboBox(string ColumnName, string selectedItem, int width)
{
    string[] data = { "Date", "LEInt", "String" };

    ComboBox dgCmbCol = new ComboBox();
    dgCmbCol.ItemsSource = data;
    dgCmbCol.Name = ColumnName;
    dgCmbCol.Width = width;
    dgCmbCol.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
    dgCmbCol.SelectionChanged += DataTypeSelectionChanged;
    return dgCmbCol;
}

// This reads a JSON file and uses it's options to set the width of all the columns
// for the DataGrid and matches the ComboBoxes to it so they all line up
dynamic TableData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Config.DataLayoutDefinition);
ComboBoxPanel.Children.Clear(); //Since this is run on user interaction, clear old contents.

for (int i = 0; i <  DataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    int width = TableData.data[i].ColumnWidth;
    if (TableData.data[i].DataType == "String")
    {
        width = 125;
    }
    else if (TableData.data[i].DataType == "Date")
    {
        width = 150;
    }
    else if (TableData.data[i].DataType == "LEInt")
    {
        width = 80;
    }
    else
    {
        width = 100;
    }
ComboBoxPanel.Children.Add(CreateComboBox(TableData.data[i].Column.ToString(), TableData.data[i].DataType.ToString(), width));
    DataGridView.Columns[i].Width = width;

}
```